# Is there any way to convert a string to a char[] to make something like this work?

Tags: c++, string, char, initializer

I'm trying to get the number of characters in the string without using any library functions.

I'm getting an "*array initializer must be an initializer list or literal string*" error.

```
using namespace std;

string stringLength(string myString) {


char string[] = myString.c_str();

while (string[i] != 0) {

//code to calculate length of char string[]

}    

int main() {

string myString = "hello";

cout << stringLength(myString) << endl;

cout << myString << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cause of error is the way you defined the string. `char string[] = ` demands that the next token be a string literal (`"Hi! I'm a string literal!"`) or a constant character array (`{'H', 'i', '!', ' ', 'I', '\', 'm', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'y', '!'}`)

Answer (score 2):

You have not one but two member functions at your disposal for determining the length of a `std::string`: [`size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) and [`length()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size). You can just use them:

```
int main() {
    string myString = "hello";
    cout << myString.length() << endl;
    cout << myString << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you really, really insist on doing it the old-fashioned C way, don't. But then the right way to pull out the internal character pointer is via either [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) or [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)

Answer (score 0):

what @Barry do is the correct way
but if this is what you want, check this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

size_t stringLength(string myString) {
    size_t count = 0;
    const char * pstr = myString.c_str();
    while (pstr[count] != 0) {
        //code to calculate length of char string[]
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}    

int main() {
    string myString = "hello";
    cout << stringLength(myString) << endl;
    cout << myString << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

myString.c_str() returns pointer to string.

```
const char* str = myString.c_str();

int length = 0;
while (*str != NULL) {
length++;
str++;
}
```